# Язык и библиотека для наиболее быстрого парсинга Excel

Tags: excel

Может кто встречал некую сводную таблицу, в которой были бы указаны языки/библиотеки и время парсинга Excel(.xlsx)? 
Или кто-то сам делал замеры

Comment: Уточните формат файлов excel для парсинга

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-programming-language-for-manipulating-files-with-content-from-Microsoft-Excel